# list index out of range (with while loop)

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm working on an a assignment for an edx course and I'm having an "index out of range" error in my code when it runs a while loop, even though it gives the right output eventually.

This is my code:

```
# [] create The Weather
# [] copy and paste in edX assignment page
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/world_temp_mean.csv -o mean_temp.txt

mean_temp = open('mean_temp.txt', 'a+')
mean_temp.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")

mean_temp.seek(0)

headings = mean_temp.readline().split(',')

city_temp = mean_temp.readline().split(',')
while city_temp:
    print(headings[0].capitalize(), "of", city_temp[0], headings[2], "is", city_temp[2], "Celsius")
    city_temp = mean_temp.readline().split(',')

mean_temp.close()
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? Just saying "it has a xxx error" isn't **a clear problem statement**. Please demonstrate a [mcve].

Comment: Not a solution to the specific problem, but you can simplify your code a lot by replacing the while loop and readline's with `for line in mean_temp:` and make it easier to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Hint: You'll immediately know where it went wrong just by inserting `print(city_temp)` right before the existing print statement. It doesn't take a few seconds.

Comment: Before your print statement in the while loop, use `if len(headings) > 0` and you should be good. This doesn't work probably because you have an extra line at the end of the file or something.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this and it should work. I think your while clause isn't correctly finding the end of the file - a for loop works and is cleaner.

```py
with open("mean_temp.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("\nRio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0")

with open("mean_temp.txt", "r") as f:
    headings = f.readline().split(',')
    for next_line in f:
        next_line = next_line.split(',')
        print(headings[0].capitalize(), "of", next_line[0], headings[2], "is", next_line[2], "Celsius")
```

Comment: The same problem seems to occur when there is no blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: @tobias_k I've edited the answer and it should now work. Let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the empty last line, i.e. `''`, the result of `mean_temp.readline().split(',')` is `['']`, not `[]`, hence your loop continues and you get the index error. You could check the `len` instead:

```
while len(city_temp) == 4:
    print(headings[0].capitalize(), "of", city_temp[0], headings[2], "is", city_temp[2], "Celsius")
    city_temp = mean_temp.readline().split(',')
```

However, the better way to handle this would be with a proper `for` loop and `csv` reader:

```
import csv
with open('mean_temp.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    for city in reader:
        print(header[0].capitalize(), "of", city[0], header[2], "is", city[2], "Celsius")
```

(The file format would work even better with a `DictReader`, but the way you print that line doesn't.)

Comment: Thank you! I just don't understand where the [''] in the last line is coming from.

Comment: @Renves Well, the last line in your file is an empty line, i.e. `''`, and if you split that by `','` (or really anything else) you get `['']`, i.e. a single segment that is the entire line.